# No airflow on any driver side vents

Tags: ac, hvac, oldsmobile

1993 Oldsmobile 98 Regency Elite.

Hello,

I have an odd problem where the driver side vents have almost no airflow coming out of them. This is for all positions, so no combination of defrost/vent/heat/combined makes any difference.

The passenger side is acting fine and blows pretty strong and hot.

Any ideas? I have the kick panel off and the glove box out, but I can't see any sort of actuator that isn't working.

Does anyone have a diagram of the layout? Is it even possible for an actuator to BLOCK the air going to the driver side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the passenger side vents are working correctly, I'd guess that you've got a blockage somewhere. I doubt the actuator itself could block it, but it is entirely possible for a foreign object to get stuck in there and block it up - your most likely suspect is leaves, they get blown into the inlet every autumn (fall) and gradually build up inside the pipes until they stop the airflow, or stop the actuators moving...